# Should I store all my Product information in Product objects or split it between Product object and CMS Page?

Tags: architecture, content-management-system, e-commerce

I have a CMS app I'm building and I'm adding ecommerce functionality.  I'm pondering a design choice and wondered if anyone had thoughts?

I have product model objects, and a page in the CMS which is describing each product.  Logically I'm wondering if all information about a product should go in the product model or if some should go in the CMS page.  Either approach will work no doubt, I'm just wondering if anyone has thoughts on which may be best and why.

Storing the information in separate Product model and CMS Page models seems more logical, as some information belongs to the product and some information belongs to the page.

So the Product stores things which are inherent properties of the product. Eg: Name, Price Images, Features, and the Page stores things which are for selling the product. Eg, benefits, how it works diagram, sales info.

But I think storing all the info in the one model is more pragmatic. If I have a separate CMS page and product, a user will need to enter and maintain information in two places, a user could also end up unintentionally tying the wrong product to the wrong page, and to take a product offline would require disabling two things.

I think I sometimes spend way too long thinking about these things. Any thoughts? I think I'm favouring the pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I think storing all the info in
>   the one model is more pragmatic. If I
>   have a seperate CMS page and product,
>   a user will need to enter and maintain
>   information in two places, a user
>   could also end up uninentionally
>   tieing the wrong product to the wrong
>   page, and to take a product offline
>   would require disabling two things.

No, it isn't.

You are assuming that the final product DB will be managed by just one person, but in reality the "hard data" and the "marketing copy" should be generated (and maintained) by two different categories of users with different skills, goals and roles. Maybe this means a single person who wears two (or more) "hats" but this should not be considered as a reason to bundle everything in a big object record.

Taking a product offline does not require you to make two different actions. I'd model this as a boolean flag on the main (hard data) product record (i.e.: active<->Y/N) and would enable or disable the relevant CMS page depending on this.

Depending on the specifics, btw, the CMS page could still be searchable, or displayed, and the only part that would be grayed out would be the "put in the basket" button (this way a customer can see that the specific item was offered in the past, but not anymore).

So, Item descriptive qualities (size, etc.) should be part of the Item record. 
Anything "sales related", i.e. "blurb", suggestions for other items, sales discount, s&h remarks etc. should be part of the CMS page (or record).
And the CMS page should always render some data from the Item record, because it's useful in itself (customer can check if it's too big, or underpowered etc.) and will provide a baseline info to put in the CMS page in case the copy editor hasn't provided anything yet.